# How to compare and merge lists using linq or moreLinq

Tags: c#, linq, morelinq

I have two lists of type KeyValuePair.

Values are as following

```
List A
2019-01-01 1
2019-01-02 0
2019-01-03 1

List B
2019-01-01 0
2019-01-03 1
```

I want to merge these two list so it looks like this

```
List C 

2019-01-01 0 //item from list B 
2019-01-02 0 //item from list A, missing date in List B
2019-01-03 1 //item from list A - items are the same in list A and B
```

Is there a way with Linq or MoreLinq that can actually do this, ie.

- merge items from two lists
- use item from list A if same item does not exist in list B
- replace item from list A with item from list B if they are not equal

Comment: You need a left outer join.  See msdn : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: What do you mean with " if same item does not exist"? What is "same"? Do you only look for the dates or combination of date/value?

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič date/value

Comment: Please, read this: [Enumerable.Intersect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=netframework-4.7.2) and this: [Enumerable.Except](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Why isn't then "2019-01-01 1" from B in list C?

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič there is no such item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know you can never have a default `DateTime` as the key:

```
var r = from a in ListA
join b in ListB on a.Key equals b.Key into joined
from b in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
select b.Key != default(DateTime) ? b : a;
```

If you might have a default `DateTime` then convert the keys to a `DateTime?` and back again to detect the missing case reliably:

```
var r = from a in ListA.Select(kv => new KeyValuePair<DateTime?, int>(kv.Key, kv.Value))
join b in ListB.Select(kv => new KeyValuePair<DateTime?, int>(kv.Key, kv.Value))
on a.Key equals b.Key into joined
from b in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>(b.Key ?? a.Key.GetValueOrDefault(), b.Value);
```

Note that in both we skip the rule "replace item from list A with item from list B if they are not equal" with just "use the item from B if it exists" because we have to check if B exists anyway, and if B's value is the same as A's then it doesn't matter that we still used it.

I'd probably just build a dictionary from A and then replace the values with those from B unless I really cared about order, though.

Answer (score 2):

I formulated something like this. Please check:

```
var q =
    from a in ListA
    join b in ListB on a.Dt equals b.Dt into j
    from b in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new { Date=a.dt, Val = a.val == b?.val ? a.val : (b?.val ?? a.val)  };
```

Comment: That was the basic idea, but I was trying to see is there a way out with a morelinq extension method such as listA.OrderedMerge(listB). BTW you are doing (b.val ?? a.val) on non null values

Comment: perhaps b itself is null. I will check it out soon

Comment: I dont want to byb, but b can also be KeyValuePair not just a class.

Comment: It is not with morelinq but  it is now working. Both lists can be KeyValuePair. It does not change anything.

Comment: You cannot do (b?.val ?? a.val) with a b being of type KeyValuePair.

Answer (score 0):

Please, read my comment to the question first.

Another way is to use [Union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union?view=netframework-4.7.2) with [GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
var result = ListB
    .Union(ListA)
    .GroupBy(kvp=>kvp.Key)
    .Select(grp=> new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>(grp.Key, grp.Select(v=>v.Value).First()))
    .OrderBy(kvp=>kvp.Key);
```

**Note #1:** i think it's less efficient than `join`.

**Note #2:** there's probably more ways to achieve that, i.e via using: [Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netframework-4.7.2), [SkipWhile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skipwhile?view=netframework-4.7.2), [TakeWhile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.takewhile?view=netframework-4.7.2) etc.

**Note #3:** i've made above example to show how useful, flexible and funny is Linq ;)